# Pass var from a class to a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want the var postKey value to another ViewController named: ExtraViewController. The value of the first var postKey need to go in the var postKey of the ExtraViewController. This is what i have so far.

```
var postKey = Database.database().reference().childByAutoId().key

        let ExtraViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExtraViewController") as! ExtraViewController

        ExtraViewController.postKey = postKey
```

> Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard' Error: Expected
>   declaration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code-

```
func moveToOtherView()
{
    var postKey = Database.database().reference().childByAutoId().key
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let extraViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExtraViewController") as! ExtraViewController
    extraViewController.postKey = postKey
}
```

Comment: Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard' Error: Expected declaration

Comment: Yes i have copy and pasted it

Comment: The ViewController with the first var postKey is an class called "class Post".

Comment: This is a very low quality answer, where is the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** create **object** with name which names matches with any class `ExtraViewController`

Replace your code

```
    let ExtraViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExtraViewController") as! ExtraViewController

    ExtraViewController.postKey = postKey
```

With

```
    let extraViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExtraViewController") as! ExtraViewController

    extraViewController.postKey = postKey
```

Comment: Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard' Error: Expected declaration

Comment: @DaniKemper You have both view controller in same storyboard ?

Comment: No, The ViewController with the first var postKey is an class called "class Post".